# Font awesome Version 3.2.1 works version 4 Does Not

Tags: css, fonts

Ok I have a site that I am working on where we have to host the Font Awesome files on our server we can't use CDN.

Anyway if I download version 3.2.1 it works with no problem.  If I upgrade to version 4 and beyond the fonts don't show.  The CSS files look identical (as far as the folder it is looking for the font files in). I change the way I call the fonts for version 4 using fa- instead of icon-.  Yet only version 3 fonts work.  Any idea what might be going on? I am not at liberty to link to the site.

Comment: Can you add a snippet reproducing the problem? You can add it to your question through the `<>` button in the editor when you edit the question.

Comment: Upgrading from 3.2.1 to 4   https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4  u should use the base class "fa" Example using fa-4 <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>